# Setting state object dynamically using the data returned using Promise.all and fetch API : React+Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, fetch, setstate

I am using fetch API and promise.all for a scenario where I am passing an array of URL'S from where I am fetching the data. The data retrieved from all the above URL'S needs to be set to the state object.

Say I have an array of 5 URL's , the result returned by these must be 
assigned to the 5 different values inside my state object.

Using React along with typescript.

Help would be appreciated.

This is what I have tried so far

```
import * as React from 'react';

const urls = [ 'http://localhost:3001/url1',
               'http://localhost:3001/url2',
               'http://localhost:3001/url3',
             ]

interface IState {
     test: [],
     result: [],
     returnVal: []
}

export default class App extends React.Component<{},IState> {

  constructor(props:any)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       test: [],
       result: [],
       returnVal: []
  }

  checkStatus(response:any) {
    if (response.ok) {
      return Promise.resolve(response);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
    }
  }

  parseJSON(response:any) {
    return response.json();
  }

  setData(data:any){
    Object.entries(this.state).forEach(([key], index) => {
      this.setState({ [key]: data[index] })
    });
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
          fetch(url)
            .then(this.checkStatus)                 
            .then(this.parseJSON)
            .catch(error => console.log('There was a problem!', error))
        ))
        .then(data => {
           this.setData(data);
        })
  }

  render() {  
    return(
      //some rendering code
    )
  }
}
```

Need to set the data returned from promise to the state object variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
      fetch(url)
        .then(this.checkStatus)                 
        .then(this.parseJSON)
 ))
 .then(jsons => {
    var newState = {};
    var index = 0;
    for(var key in this.state)
       newState[key] = jsons[index++];        
    this.setState(newState);
})
```

Comment: Say my resultant state does not have this consecutive properties i.e., data1 ,data2 etc. I have updated the state object

Comment: @velsonjr Ok, look at updated answer, main idea still the same.

Comment: I quite did not get this one. What is the 'data' referring to? Could you please give me the entire Promise section? Are you referring to "jsons" as in "newState[key] = jsons[index++]; "

Comment: @velsonjr, yes it's my typo, look at updated answer.

Comment: That was a minor mistake. I fixed it . Thanks though !